# Why my windowning system is x11 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, xorg, gnome-shell, wayland, 20.04

I fresh installed the new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But When I check my windowing system its x11. But I was expecting to have it may be Wayland.

Again I try to edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` Uncommenting `#WaylandEnable=false` to `true` and restart gdm but there is no change.

Later when I though to install default Gnome shell I found that all I have is the Gnome on xong option. But no wayland.

Well I'm expert around these areas, please help me understand.

Comment: "But I was expecting to have it may be Wayland."  -why?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Not an expectation but just want to switch to wayland

Comment: You should be able to select it at the login screen, bottom right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu developers have labored mightily to bring Wayland onboard, and I've been using Wayland daily since 17.10.

However, there are still a few pain points that simply couldn't be overcome for 20.04 (certain video card manufacturers stand out). Migrating everybody to Wayland in the 20.04 cycle would cause too many folks' systems to break.

You can see a representative sample of the discussion at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/wayland-for-19-10

Comment: I face the same error. Ubuntu 20.04 works fine. But when update to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS it logins but when I try to open an app, "Screen repeats to showing opening app(Image frames loop - like a gif loop)". I have only option to poweroff. I restarted with older kernel, and it works now.

Comment: @SudhakarKrishnan your description suggests that you may have a very different problem than described in the question above, though the result seems similar to you. Please file a bug report for your issue.

Comment: Yes it seems similar, but different. My problem is https://askubuntu.com/q/1305622/173227 . Thankyou.