# Cannot have both WiFi and full resolution, after upgrade/Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, 20.04, display-resolution

**Update**:
If in Grub I boot to `5.4.0-60 (recovery mode)`,
I select `network`, and then I continue rebooting, I get both WiFi and full res.
I guess this helps learning how to fix the problem.

---

**OP**:
It happened to me before (in this and another Ubuntu 20.04 system that I have) that once in a while, after a reboot I have no sound and/or WiFi.
As I reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul), that happens after an automatic kernel upgrade and subsequent reboot.
For some reason, the required drivers package is not automatically installed alongside.

Today I have turned on my PC, and the only available resolution, at the console, was 640x480.
When connecting via xRDP, I got 1366x768, the resolution of my client.
I checked

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-60-generic
```

so I installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic
```

(this might have not been the right move).
After a reboot, I have again 1920x1080, but now I have no WiFi.

If rebooting and choosing kernel 5.4.0-58 in Grub, I have WiFi but 640x480, so I cannot get both.

**What is causing the problem, and what is the solution?**

**Why would I have different configurations in kernels `.58` and `.60`?**

**Some system information** below may help.
Notes:

1. I have installed `linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60` at `2021-01-14 14:00:36`.
2. There is a strange sequence of automatic operations that took place automatically, just before that, for instance:

   2.1. install linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 5.4.0-56.62

   2.2. remove linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 5.4.0-56.62
3. I have also manually attempted `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-58-generic`, after `15:00`, and I obtained that the package was already the latest version.
   I don't know if it was installed along the manual installation of `5.4.0-60` (as per log below, it doesn't seem to be the case), or automatically at about `13:47` (although log shows `status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-58.64` which I am not sure it is the same).

---

**Possibly related** (although I found no specific answer)

1. [How to fix Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade 5.8.0-](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305622/how-to-fix-ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-5-8-0)
2. [Wi-Fi unable to connect after updating nvidia proprietary driver (Linux mint 19 Cinnamon)](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=296348)

---

**Some system information**

```
$ apt-mark showmanual | grep ^linux
linux-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-40-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-40-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-58-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04

$ apt-mark showauto | grep ^linux
linux-base
linux-firmware
linux-headers-5.4.0-39
linux-headers-5.4.0-40
linux-headers-5.4.0-42
linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-58
linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-60
linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-libc-dev
linux-modules-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-40-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-modules-5.8.0-36-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic
linux-sound-base

$ cat -n /var/log/dpkg.log | grep linux- | grep nvidia
   385  2021-01-14 13:45:11 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 5.4.0-56.62
   386  2021-01-14 13:45:11 remove linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 5.4.0-56.62 <none>
   387  2021-01-14 13:45:11 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 5.4.0-56.62
   388  2021-01-14 13:45:12 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 5.4.0-56.62
   389  2021-01-14 13:45:13 status config-files linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 5.4.0-56.62
   478  2021-01-14 13:47:22 install linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 <none> 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   479  2021-01-14 13:47:22 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   480  2021-01-14 13:47:23 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   481  2021-01-14 13:47:23 upgrade linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-58.64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   482  2021-01-14 13:47:23 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-58.64
   483  2021-01-14 13:47:23 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-58.64
   484  2021-01-14 13:47:23 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-58.64
   485  2021-01-14 13:47:23 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   645  2021-01-14 13:49:27 configure linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1 <none>
   646  2021-01-14 13:49:27 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   647  2021-01-14 13:49:27 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   648  2021-01-14 13:49:28 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   653  2021-01-14 13:49:28 configure linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1 <none>
   654  2021-01-14 13:49:28 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   655  2021-01-14 13:49:28 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   656  2021-01-14 13:49:28 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
   685  2021-01-14 14:00:36 install linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 <none> 5.4.0-60.67
   686  2021-01-14 14:00:36 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 5.4.0-60.67
   687  2021-01-14 14:00:37 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 5.4.0-60.67
   689  2021-01-14 14:00:37 configure linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 5.4.0-60.67 <none>
   690  2021-01-14 14:00:37 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 5.4.0-60.67
   691  2021-01-14 14:00:38 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 5.4.0-60.67
   692  2021-01-14 14:00:41 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 5.4.0-60.67
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that kernel `5.8.0-43` is out, an update to that version solved the problem.
I guess I will never know what went wrong.

Note that I had to apply [this same solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259815/226614), with a manual installation `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic`.

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265137/avoid-missing-kernel-linux-modules-extra-xx-generic-when-updating-kernel#comment2230685_1265498), I also installed `linux-generic` and `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`.
I will wait until the next update to confirm whether everything gets updated automatically.